# MySql Communications link failure, when connecting to MySQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I have developed a applicaion in java which uses Hibernate and mysql as backend.This applicaion runs at every night 12.00 AM. The application works fine, but **some time it shows**,

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 59,390,356
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   1 milliseconds ago.   at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor66.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1118)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3055)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2941)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3489)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2275)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
>     ... 19 more Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused
>   connection abort: recv failed     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2499)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2952)  ... 27
>   more

I have connectd my application by using IP,

**192.168.0.25:3306/dbname?user=root&password=password**

Myapplication and mysql runs on the same machine only.

I have checked many forum but i cant get clear idea, any one suggest me the correct way to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you check if mysql service is running?

Comment: @Arvind yes mysql service is running.

Comment: May be MySql is running out-of max no. of connections with your app.

Comment: @Arvind If i use max no. of connection means, then how it works on mean times. I have placed some scheduler, that trigger myapplication every day night. it works fine fron Mon-Fri day. But saterday it shows that type of error.

Comment: may be you should put a schedule for sat to test mysql with logs enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Means your database has not started.
If you are using WAMP or similar server for mysql then start these server then your my sql will start

Comment: I am using xampp, and my mysql status is running only.